# Is there any another way to python manage.py crontab run in django server?

Tags: python, django, django-cron, django-crontab

i have created a scheduled job in django with django_crontab package. i have added the job. its successfully added but its only get executed whenever i run python manage.py crontab run daeea9e88c171494b1610bdebfasd123 not with runserver command. what might be the issue, this is my view.

cron.py file

```
def my_scheduled_job():
    file = open('geek.txt','w')
    now = timezone.now()
    file.write("This is the write command")
    file.write("It allows us to write in a particular file")
    file.write(str(now))
    file.close()
    print(now)
    return True
```

settings.py

```
CRONTAB_LOCK_JOBS = False
CRONTAB_DJANGO_PROJECT_NAME = 'api' 
CRONTAB_DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'api.settings'
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'app.cron.my_scheduled_job')
]
```

what i want is its job get executed every minute whenever i run python manage.py runserver. Is there anything missing please help me out.

Comment: Did you mean you are not seeing the print? I don't think it will display on whichever terminal you are on. Try to check if the file is updated every minute

Comment: Yes I checked file, i am keeping a file for that. File only get updated whenever i called python manage.py crontab run.. Not on runserver.

Comment: It should be run every minute regardless if you used runserver, because cron will run it for you. Just to confirm, what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You did run `python manage.py crontab add` right? Try to see if your cron job was added on your crontab. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7060) on how. If it is there, that job will run every minute even without `runserver` or `crontab run`

Comment: yees..when i type crontab -l, it show my job with id.

Comment: Then that should be fine. It should run every minute

Comment: But not running in my case, i have used timezone.now() to check whether its updating or not. but its not coming as excepted. only get update when i running python manage.py crontab run. i have a doubt is user permission anything to do with it. whether user have permission to run cronjob.

Comment: That's possible. Because `python manage.py crontab run` runs the command directly from django.

Comment: okay. let me check that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem which is solved now.
I just need to set my user environ var in the .env file and the issue is solved.

My virtual env path :/home/nasir/Work//dj_venv/bin/python3.8

My cronjob run path :
path/home/nasir/Work/django_projects_neosoft/e_commerce/manage.py crontab run 6ef9e6b4bdce09989e8ed084d2ffc2bb

My full path (for my system) :
/home/nasir/Work/django_projects_neosoft/dj_venv/bin/python3.8 /home/nasir/Work/django_projects_neosoft/e_commerce/manage.py crontab run 6ef9e6b4bdce09989e8ed084d2ffc2bb

I paste the full path in the terminal and get errors related to the database and environ variable I set environ variables in the .env file and the issue is fixed.
cronjob is working fine now.

in your case, u may get some other errors, try to resolve it, at least u know where is the problem.